# Disable ripple effect on Chip

Tags: android, android-chips

Hi I am trying to disable the ripple effect on Chip. I tried adding `app:rippleColor` but with no luck. Is it possible at all to disable this effect on Chip?

```
 <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/filter_chip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkable="false"
            android:text="@string/filter_menu"
            app:chipEndPadding="7dp"
            app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_filter_list_24"
            app:chipIconTint="@color/black"
            app:chipStartPadding="12dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:chipSurfaceColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this app:rippleColor="@null"